# Mapping /error does not work in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am developing a spring boot application, using boot v 1.2.5,  using thymeleaf as the view technology

In my Mvc Configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class MVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/message").setViewName("message");
    registry.addViewController("/error").setViewName("errors/error");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("authentication/login");
}
```

The problem is that the first and last mapping is working fine, but the middle one "error" is not working at all !!

I am using the same rules as the other two templates, same prefix, same directory structure, so it is supposed to work like the other two !!
But, when i point my browser to /error, spring boot show the fallback error page saying that there is no mapping for /error

when i change it to:
 `registry.addViewController("/error").setViewName("errors/error");`

it works fine for /errors

Spring boot documentation states about the /error handling:
"For browser clients there is a ‘whitelabel’ error view that renders the same data in HTML format (to customize it just add a View that resolves to ‘error’)."

so, it says to add a view that resolve to error, that's what i did, but it does not work !!

so, what is the problem? why /error does not work?

Answer (score 1):

You've added a view *controller* for `/error`, not a view. This is then being overridden by Boot's own controller with a `/error` mapping. As a result, you get the default error page.

All you need to do is to provide an error view. As you're using Thymeleaf, you can do so by creating a file named `src/main/resources/templates/error.html`.